# Docusign Prefilling fields with Java and XML does not appear to work

Tags: tabs, docusignapi

I'm trying to send an envelope from a template using the REST API. I'm using Java with XML since the Java example is given with XML only. Here:
http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromTemplate

My template is very simple. It has:
1. A data field called Material1
2. A data field called Quantity1
3. A Full Name field
4. Signature field
5. Date Signed field

Here's the screen shot:
[image: Template screen shot]

The Java code I'm using is exactly as it appears in the API Walkthrough link that I provided above. The XML that I supply is:

```html
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
 <accountId>ZZZZZZZZZZ</accountId>
 <status>sent</status>
 <emailSubject>DocuSign API Call - Signature request from template
 </emailSubject>
 <templateId>1886EC14-153E-4E05-AFF8-04F508098E60</templateId>
 <templateRoles>
  <templateRole>
   <name>Michael</name>
   <email>michael@company.com</email>
   <roleName>Signer1</roleName>
   <tabs>
    <textTabs>
     <text>
      <tabLabel>\*Material1</tabLabel>
      <value>MTX80HD</value>
     </text>
     <text>
      <tabLabel>\*Quantity1</tabLabel>
      <value>11</value>
     </text>
    </textTabs>
   </tabs>
  </templateRole>
 </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

However the value of MTX80HD is not being prefilled in the Material1 Field, nor do I see 11 in the Quantity1.
I've read multiple posts here and followed every suggestion that I have found but still can't get the pre population to work. The Full Name and Date Sign are filled in however.

TIA

Edit 1:
OK. I converted the XML to JSON, as @ergin suggested below and the fields are still not prepopulated. So the issue must lie elsewhere and not with XML.

Here's the JSON I'm sending:

```html
{"account":"MyAccountId","status":"sent","emailSubject":"DocuSign API Call - Test signature request from template","templateId":"1886EC14-153E-4E05-AFF8-04F508098E60","templateRoles":[{"name":"Michael","email":"michael@company.com","roleName":"Signer1","tabs":{"textTabs":[{"tabLabel":"Material1","value":"MTX80HD"}]}}]}
```

The URL I'm sending the above JSON to is:
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/MyAccountId/envelopes

The fields I'm trying to populate with the tabs were created on the template as Data Field widgets.

I must be missing something obvious, as I see people posting that they got it to work, eventually.
Hope to hear from anyone who has any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your Template somewhere?  That might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks @mikebz. Now that I have enough rep points I added the template image to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple tabs that are using the same `tabLabel` or just one?  You only need the escape sequence when you have multiple, however even then you need an extra backslash ().  You have this

```
<tabLabel>\*Material1</tabLabel>
```

But it should be this instead:

```
<tabLabel>\\*Material1</tabLabel>
```

However if you only have one tab with the name `Material1` then don't use `\\*` at all.

Also, if you want to use JSON instead you can look at some of the other API walkthroughs in other languages that show JSON, or you can use the auto-generated REST API help page:

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help

Comment: Hi Ergin.

Thanks for the reply. I believe I only have a single tab. However, reading replies from Kim on this forum I saw her include those anyway at times. :) And since things are still not working for me I decided to try that as well. :) 

I noticed that you are suggesting JSON as the answer. Does that mean XML will not work?

I see my template image in the Original Post didn't make it, as I need 10 rep points to post images. :(

Thanks.
Rudy

Comment: Hmm no it should work with XML as well, but have you tried using JSON as a test?

Comment: Thanks @Ergin. Tried it with JSON as well, but with the same result. :(